# How can I loop through a string from the end to split it to several strings

Tags: python

2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
2015_Copa_AmÃ©rica_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents
2016_Summer_Olympics_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents 2018_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents 2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_mobile-web_all-agents A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_en.wikipedia.org_desktop_all-agents

I have a column in my dataset with the above as some of the observations from that column. I'm trying to separate the column into 4 columns such that I have one column as 2014_FIFA_World_Cup, 2015_Copa_AmÃ©rica, 2016_Summer_Olympics; another column as en.wikipedia.org, en.wikipedia.org, en.wikipedia.org; another as all-access, mobile-web, desktop.

I've tried the following

`long_string = """2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents`
`2015_Copa_AmÃ©rica_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents`
`2016_Summer_Olympics_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents`
`2018_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents`
`2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_mobile-web_all-agents`
`A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire_en.wikipedia.org_desktop_all-agents"""`

`lines = long_string.split("\n")`

`columns = [line.split("_") for line in lines]`

`print(columns)`

Got the following result:

`[['2014', 'FIFA', 'World', 'Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2015', 'Copa', 'AmÃ©rica', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2016', 'Summer', 'Olympics', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2018', 'FIFA', 'World', 'Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2014', 'FIFA', 'World', 'Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'mobile-web', 'all-agents'], ['A', 'Song', 'of', 'Ice', 'and', 'Fire', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'desktop', 'all-agents']]`

What I actually want is something like

`[['2014 FIFA World Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2015 Copa AmÃ©rica', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2016 Summer Olympics', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2018 FIFA World Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents'], ['2014 FIFA World Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'mobile-web', 'all-agents'], ['A Song of Ice', 'and', 'Fire', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'desktop', 'all-agents']]`

Comment: Please use triple backticks ``` to format your code

Comment: Do you want to handle only `en.wikipedia.org` or can you get `fr.wikipedia.org` for exemple?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
s = "2014_FIFA_World_Cup_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents"
my_list = [v for v in s.rsplit("_",3)]
# my_list = ['2014_FIFA_World_Cup', 'en.wikipedia.org', 'all-access', 'all-agents']
```

It can be separated, but it makes the trick. And you just have to do it for each srting in the column (and append it).

**EDIT:** This is valid as long as you always have in the end something like this: *_en.wikipedia.org_all-access_all-agents* (where 3 and only 3 "_" characters will be present dividing the desired elements).

Comment: First time seeing `::` it's magic :)

Comment: @re-za Yeah! But actually I forgot you had `rsplit`, this way it's much cleanear, because the split is from the back. I've edited and replacd it in the answer. So no more `::`

Answer (score 0):

If any of the column value is a known/fixed value, then following snippet will work

```
lines = long_string.split(" ")
print(lines)

columns = []
for line in lines:
    column = []
    a = line.split("_en.wikipedia.org_")
    column.append(a[0].replace('_', ' '))
    column.append("en.wikipedia.org")
    column.extend(a[1].split("_"))
    columns.append(column)
    
print(columns)
```

Here `en.wikipedia.org` considered as common for all columns